# Bump version with sed in package.json

Tags: json, sed

I need to make an automatic bump of *package.json* in *jenkins*, and really stuck with it.

The following `sed` command works in a pipeline but it changes the second field, I need to change the third one:

```
sed -i  "/version/s/\\([.]\\)\\(.\\)\\(.*\\)/\\1${BUILD_NUMBER}\\3/" package.json
```

Output:

```
"version": "0.222.0"
```

but I need:

```
"version": "0.0.222"
```

a part of *json* input:

```
{
 "name": "render",
  "version": "0.0.0"
  "description": "",
 "main": "./dist/index.js",
   "bin": {
"render-ne": "./bin/re"
  },
```

Who can assist with it?

Comment: Add sample JSON input.   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you know what `\\1${BUILD_NUMBER}\\3/` is doing?  It is explicitly keeping the 1st and 3rd values.  If you want to replace the third, reorder it and make the 3 a 2.  But you probably should try to understand what your command is doing before you run it in production.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if i do 
    ```sed -i  "/version/s/\\([.]\\)\\(.\\)\\(.*\\)/\\3${BUILD_NUMBER}\\2/" package.json ```

i received the -   `"version": "0.0"222`

if i do:  
 `sed -i  "/version/s/\\([.]\\)\\(.\\)\\(.*\\)/\\1${BUILD_NUMBER}\\2/" package.json` 

i received  - `"version": "0.2220`

Comment: @GillesQuenot added

Comment: Your regex is not restricting the line in the best way.  That is, it would be nice if \1.\2.\3 mapped to the major.minor.patch of your version.  Tweak the regex so that is the case.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if i know how to do this i will not ask here, and i asked for an assistance...

Comment: This is not really good because you are removing the `,` (comma) on the line. Your JSON is invalid !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the field format is as was presented, (*i.e.*: `"version": "0.0.0"`), then those [*back references*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) aren't really necessary here.  Just `s`*ubstitute* the text after the final `.`:

```
sed  -i '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"${BUILD_NUMBER}\"/" package.json
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to interpret bash vars inside my sed expression. I used this for a Chrome extension manifest.json. `sed -ie 's|\(.*"version"\): "\(.*\)",.*|\1: '"\"$new_version\"|" manifest.json` in case anyone else needs it (this sed expression could be cleaned up a bit heh).

Answer (score 1):

If you tried [the accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616813/3025856) on **MacOS X**, you get the following results:

> sed: 1: "package.json": extra characters at the end of p command

After searching for similar issue found that on Darwin, `sed` is slightly different; this worked for me:

```
sed -i '' '/version/s/[^.]*$/'"${BUILD_NUMBER}\",/" package.json
```

I hope this helps someone who came here looking for an answer but found that the solution was not for *all* versions of sed.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac -

Create a file called `version-bump.sh` with the following

> **RUN THIS IN THE ROOT OF YOUR REPO OR UPDATE PATH TO PACKAGE.JSON**

```bash
VERSION_STRING='"version": '
CURR_VERSION=$(awk -F \" '/"version": ".+"/ { print $4; exit; }' package.json)
NEXT_VERSION=$(echo ${CURR_VERSION} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF += 1 ; print}')

sed -i '' "s/\($VERSION_STRING\).*/\1\"$NEXT_VERSION\",/" package.json
```

‍